# Redhat High Availability Add-On on Centos 5.8

Tags: centos, redhat, centos5

could we use Redhat High availability Add-On on CentOS 5.8 server?
in other words should we purchase a license for Redhat high availability clustering for CentOS 5.8 or its included in CentOS without any charge?

We are going to have a clustering in a project and Redhat clustering add-on is required. i want to know that could we use CentOS with clustering instead of purchasing redhat OS and its Add-On licenses?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The packages included in these Red Hat add-ons are already present in CentOS. You don't need to do anything to begin using them.

Comment: Can you provide some guidance on how to achieve the same as the packaged Red Hat product?

Comment: @ewwhite Read the Red Hat documentation, and skip the parts about adding channels and RHN subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used redhat 5/centos 5 for awhile. I think the steps are the similar.  However I do recall 5 had quite a few cluster issues.  I'd suggest 6.

1) get your ip addresses.  each node you want a "public facing" ip, a heartbeat ip, and then a floating/cluster ip (for active node)
2) need a method to fence.  this is big with redhat/centos.  Usually with HP or IBM hardware you can use the ILO/IMM.
3) shared storage (for data and quorum)

btw, most centos/redhat tutorials/docs say to avoid using quorum disk because timings are hard to configure.  They are hard to configure, but in a two node cluster I prefer to still have quorum disk

To install your cluster, have your media installed

yum install ricci (for management)
yum install luci (cluster)

Set a password for the ricci user (you will use this later to add node to cluster)

You will see a few new services pop up.  For management
luci
ricci
modclusterd

For cluster 
cman
rgmanager

At this point, if you start luci, ricci, and modclusterd, you can now point your web browser to one of your nodes port 8084

http://[node]:8084

And here is where you would start creating your cluster.  You can log in as root if you like.  When you add the nodes, you want to use the ricci user password.

This should give you a good start.   I'll likely blog something more detailed soon to build this since it seems a popular question.

Cheers!